# Why is withAnimation changing how these references are managed?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In the following code, including one less line in a `withAnimation` block triggers an `unowned reference` fault. Dismissing the view shown by button A and B should trigger the addition of a new element in both case. However, B causes the reference to the `items` list to be invalid:

```swift
struct ListItem: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

class MyListClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [ListItem]()
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var item: ListItem

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField("Name", text: self.$item.name)
        }
    }
}

struct MyListView: View {
    @StateObject var myList = MyListClass()
    @State private var itemDraft = ListItem(name: "Foo")
    @State private var showingA = false
    @State private var showingB = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(myList.items) { item in
                // Pass binding to item into DetailsView
                Text(item.name)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: Button(action: {
                    showingA.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("A")
                },
                trailing: Button(action: {
                    showingB.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("B")
                }
            )
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingA) {
                DetailView(item: $itemDraft)
                    .onDisappear { // Closure A
                        let newItem = itemDraft
                        withAnimation {
                            itemDraft = ListItem(name: "Bar")
                            myList.items.append(newItem) // <- here
                        }
                    }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingB) {
                DetailView(item: $itemDraft)
                    .onDisappear { // Closure B
                        let newItem = itemDraft
                        itemDraft = ListItem(name: "Bar")
                        withAnimation {
                            myList.items.append(newItem) // <- and here
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is

```
Attempted to read an unowned reference but the object was already deallocated
```

What is the difference in references management between closures A (annotation above) and B? (Bonus points: what tool of xcode is the most useful to find the source of that bug?)

Comment: I would use an environment object or an injected dependency to your view rather than `@StateObject`.

Comment: works without any problems for me on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, target ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. 
Tested on macOS 12 and iPhone ios 15.

Comment: As I understand it, in ios 14.x and macos 11.x, there should be no more than 1 sheet modifier 
on a particular view. So you could try to "attach" one sheet to the Text("A") and the other to Text("B").
Let us know if this makes a difference.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, thanks, it is an env object in the app where that behavior occurred, I only tried to make a simple test case

Comment: @workingdog Original code only has one sheet, it makes no difference but it's still interesting to know there's a limit on theses. Your test indicates that this may be a bug... thanks for it. I'm on xcode 12.5, target ios 14.0, tested on ios 14.6.